# How to write a word at a time to *char?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I'm trying to implement a version of memset to write a word at a time instead of byte-by-byte.
The code I'm currently working with is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* set in memory one word at a time
    dest:  destination 
    ch:    the character to write
    count: how many copies of ch to make in dest */
void wmemset(char *dest, int ch, size_t count) {
    long long int word;                    // 64-bit word
    unsigned char c = (unsigned char) ch;  // explicit conversion
    int i, loop, remain;

    for (i = 0, word = 0; i < 8 ; ++i) {
        word |= ((long long int)c << i * 8);
    }

    loop = count / 8;
    remain = count % 8;

    for (i = 0; i < loop; ++i, dest += 8) {
        *dest = word;    // not possible to set 64-bit to char
    }
    for (i = 0; i < remain; ++i, ++dest) {
        *dest = c;
    }
}

int main() {
    char *c;
    c = (char *) malloc(100);
    wmemset(c, 'b', 100);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        printf("%c", c[i]);

}
```

I thought the 64-bit word would overflow to the rest of the byte of the pointer but it doesn't seem so.
How do I set one word at a time?

EDIT: added a few more comments and added main function.

Comment: Please see [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What is `count` and how is `dest` declared. That will be shown in an MCVE.

Comment: In general, you have to worry about `dest` not pointing to a word-aligned location.  You might need to do a few byte assignments to get `dest` properly aligned, then the big moves, then the trailing byte assignments.  You might decide you only want to do the 'big move' code if the count is big enough to warrant the construction and so on.  You certainly shouldn't set `word` until you know it will be used.

Comment: You would need to cast `dest` to an `long long int *` before assigning: `*(long long *)dest = word;`.  `*dest` is just a `char`.

Comment: Thanks. The cast to `*(long long *) dest = word` does the trick.

Comment: Also, have you checked the `memset` from your compiler and verified that this is not what it is already doing?

Comment: I'm trying an exercise that says to implement word memset and check it against library defined memset. So, no need to check the memset from compiler.